Clicking on popup with selenium
Trying to click on this button but cannot:
last attempt:
 # Attempt to locate and click the 'Start' button
try:
    start_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Start']"))
    )
    start_button.click()

Any ideas why this fails or alternative approaches to achieve?


Perhaps the "Start" text is not on the button itself, but some sub-element inside of the button.  Expand the button element in the inspector window to see if that is the case.

Two other possibilities I can think of: maybe the element is in an <iframe> (in which case you'd need to switch to the iframe before interacting with it). Otherwise the site may be detecting your usage of a bot and preventing you from proceeding. Are you getting an exception?
